# PHP add "" after/before a variable

Tags: php

Hi I was wondering to add "" after/before a variable.

CODE:

```
<?php
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
$entry = "$entry";
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/.swf/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = ',';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $entry);
}
?>
```

Echos out

```
word1,word2,word3,etc
```

I want it to echo out:
"word1","word2","word3",etc instead
How can you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode) and [`implode`](http://www.php.net/implode):

```
$string = '"' . implode('","', explode(',', $string)) . '"';
```

or simply [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$string = '"' . str_replace(',', '","', $string) . '"';
```

Edit:

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
<?php
    $entries = array();

    while (($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
            $entries[] = basename($entry);
        }
    }

    echo '"' . implode('","', $entries) . '"';
?>
```

Comment: Thats what I want but it echos out this:"word1,""word2,"etc

Comment: @FrostyGamer150 Check out my edit. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Nope, the first one you posted is great but my come is gone.word1,""word2,"etc i want it to be "word1","word2",etc

Comment: NVM. I fixed it, I edit MY code. Your code worked great! :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just append them in your echo statement:

```
echo "\"" . preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $entry) . "\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and `implode`

```
 <?php

    $all = array();

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
        $all[] = '"'.str_replace('.swf', '', $entry).'"';

    echo implode(', ', $all);
```